# How to create draw.io database diagram in Confluence from Excel?

Tags: database, confluence

I have a a list of fields in Excel which are the fields/columns of a table in my database.
I want to convert this into a database diagram (ERD) in Confluence using draw.io. But I can't seem to be able to just copy and paste the list. Is there another way to do it?

Currently I am copying it one by one, but it is extremely tedious as the text editing in draw.io is really crappy. I need to click and click and struggle to get the next box in my table list. Then I copy and paste a field from Excel. Then draw.io puts a space in front of the text and in the next line. Then I need to click away and back again to edit it, to remove the blank space and move the text up.
I am used to Visio, where you can simply copy and paste a list, or at least when you press enter or tab, it adds a new row and automatically lets you edit the text.
There must be a better way to do this in Confluence? please help? this is agonising.

This is an example of the list I have:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYuJK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thnx to this handy link... https://drawio-app.com/entity-relationship-diagrams-with-draw-io/

You simply go to:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICqTv.png)

Then in the box that pops up you type in :

```
my_table:
zendesk_ticket_id
assignee_id
ticket_type
status
zendesk_group_name
subject
description
comment_count
reply_count
requester_id
submitter_id
```

stunning work around!